# Does there exist a Fourier series with such properties?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, fourier-series

I am looking for a series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_ne^{int}$ with the following properties :

$\bullet a_0=0$

$\bullet a_n=a_{-n} \geq 0$ for all $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

$\bullet \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_n < +\infty$

$\bullet \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|n|a_n = +\infty$

$\bullet$ It is easy to prove that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}a_ne^{int} \sim1+r(t)$ with $t/r(t)\rightarrow 0$ near $0$

Does somebody have an idea of a series which satisfy those, or a proof of its existence which is not too hard or too long?

I have done my own research and am pretty sure I have found an elementary example : $a_n=\frac{1}{|n|^b}$ with $1<b<2$ whenever $n \neq 0$. This satisfies everything except the "easiness" condition for the asymptotics computation, as it involves Mellin Transform and residues... which is tedious. I would like to eschew using high-powered results as much as possible.

I have tried computing Fourier coefficients of functions satisfying the asymptotics near $0$ but have not found anything satisfactory so far. I would like the easiest example you can think of.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just a thought: if you are concerned with the behavior as $t\to 0$, perhaps one can use that $a_n=a_{-n}$ makes this a cosine series, and $\cos(t)=1-t^2/2 + O(t^4)$?

Comment: @Aaron yes I have thought about this, but how do you deduce asymptotics of a series knowing the asymptotics of the general term? Is the asymptotics of the series the sum of the asymptotics of the general terms ? There will be a cos(nt) with $n$ going to infinity which is going to be a problem

Answer (score 1):

If you take for granted the fact that

$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}, $$

choosing

$$ a_n= \begin{cases} 0 &; n=0 \\ \frac{3}{\pi^2 n^2} & ; n\neq 0
 \end{cases} $$

satisfies all but the "easiness" condition that you mentioned. I'm not sure how you verify that condition, but maybe it would apply here?

Comment: I agree with this but it's very close to what I found (except I would replace 2 with something a little bit smaller, like 1.99, as I made a mistake in the initial post, it should be 1+remainder with remainder going slower to 0 than t, which I mistakenly wrote off as o(t)). Anyway this should be fine as an answer if you knew an easy way out of the asymptotic calculation  for any exponent >1 and <2 which is what I am struggling with and want to avoid